# C# .Net Firebase - How to logout ? why isEmailVerified always return false?

Tags: c#, .net, firebase-authentication

I'm using FirebaseAuthentication.net and FirebaseDatabase.net NuGet package in my WPF app. But I had been facing some problems.

I already created some users by using `CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password)` function and verified. At first time login (by using `SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync` function), It's Work but `IsEmailVerified` field always returns false. Then the next login always gives me a "Wrong password" exception although the password is correct.

Here is the screenshot when I click on the link in the verification email:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZhvy.png

Update: Solved, After 1day on google, I edit the library myself, change the base URL of REST API for function SendVerifyEmail to [https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:sendOobCode?key={0}](https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:sendOobCode?key=%7B0%7D).
Wow, It's work

Comment: The Firebase Authentication SDK caches the user's ID token (which contains all information about the user) for an hours, and then automatically refreshes it. Until the ID token is refreshed, the user information in the app may not reflect the latest values from the server. To ensure you detect the updated user, you can either sign them out and in again, or force a refresh of the ID token: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#getIdToken(boolean).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But I don't know how to logout too! I'm not good at JavaScrip or any Web language, so my only solution is the .Net Nuget package, unfortunately, This package doesn't give me any function to logout!

I know Firesharp and FirebaseSharp, but these packages do not provide any authentication feature. Do you know any .Net NuGet package that gives me with full authentication feature?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that even though the user is created, the email address is not verified yet. Which means the registration is successful but the email is not yet verified.

in order to enable Email link sign-in for your Firebase project,

> To sign in users by email link, you must first enable the Email provider and Email link sign-in method for your Firebase project:
>
> In the Firebase console, open the Auth section.
> On the Sign in method tab, enable the Email/Password provider. Note that email/password sign-in must be enabled to use email link sign-in.
> In the same section, enable Email link (passwordless sign-in) sign-in method.
> Click Save.

then

> To initiate the authentication flow, present the user with an interface that prompts the user to provide their email address and then call `sendSignInLinkToEmail` to request that Firebase send the authentication link to the user's email.

[Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth)

Comment: Thank you, as above question, I have confirmed that the account is verified. All the steps you listed above I have also followed, but the results have not changed
.

Comment: account is verified but email address is not. it is not the same thing

Comment: Pls, check the screenshot I've update on the question above. Thank you